# How to determine proportion of variance explained in factor analysis

Tags: variance, factor-analysis

How can I determine proportion of variation explained by 2 factors obtained in output of following code of factor analysis using pacakge "rela" in R:

```
> paf(as.matrix(mtcars))
[[1]]
[1] "PRINCIPAL AXIS FACTORING"

$Correlation
          mpg      cyl     disp       hp      drat       wt      qsec       vs        am     gear      carb
mpg   1.00000 -0.85216 -0.84755 -0.77617  0.681172 -0.86766  0.418684  0.66404  0.599832  0.48028 -0.550925
cyl  -0.85216  1.00000  0.90203  0.83245 -0.699938  0.78250 -0.591242 -0.81081 -0.522607 -0.49269  0.526988
disp -0.84755  0.90203  1.00000  0.79095 -0.710214  0.88798 -0.433698 -0.71042 -0.591227 -0.55557  0.394977
hp   -0.77617  0.83245  0.79095  1.00000 -0.448759  0.65875 -0.708223 -0.72310 -0.243204 -0.12570  0.749812
drat  0.68117 -0.69994 -0.71021 -0.44876  1.000000 -0.71244  0.091205  0.44028  0.712711  0.69961 -0.090790
wt   -0.86766  0.78250  0.88798  0.65875 -0.712441  1.00000 -0.174716 -0.55492 -0.692495 -0.58329  0.427606
qsec  0.41868 -0.59124 -0.43370 -0.70822  0.091205 -0.17472  1.000000  0.74454 -0.229861 -0.21268 -0.656249
vs    0.66404 -0.81081 -0.71042 -0.72310  0.440278 -0.55492  0.744535  1.00000  0.168345  0.20602 -0.569607
am    0.59983 -0.52261 -0.59123 -0.24320  0.712711 -0.69250 -0.229861  0.16835  1.000000  0.79406  0.057534
gear  0.48028 -0.49269 -0.55557 -0.12570  0.699610 -0.58329 -0.212682  0.20602  0.794059  1.00000  0.274073
carb -0.55093  0.52699  0.39498  0.74981 -0.090790  0.42761 -0.656249 -0.56961  0.057534  0.27407  1.000000

$Anti.Image.Cov
            mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb
mpg   0.1309842  0.0021468 -0.0123557  0.0237541 -0.0204664  0.0336169 -0.0305039 -0.0053454 -0.0418918 -0.0148400  0.0067390
cyl   0.0021468  0.0650104 -0.0144161 -0.0138921  0.0375069  0.0067937  0.0235644  0.0365639  0.0280907  0.0382301 -0.0205128
disp -0.0123557 -0.0144161  0.0450565 -0.0357554 -0.0111418 -0.0381530  0.0234403  0.0099106  0.0063967 -0.0056446  0.0494742
hp    0.0237541 -0.0138921 -0.0357554  0.0972007  0.0105565  0.0220001  0.0058275 -0.0381702 -0.0138610 -0.0143631 -0.0556935
drat -0.0204664  0.0375069 -0.0111418  0.0105565  0.2930965  0.0144280  0.0114941 -0.0063444 -0.0299061 -0.0149503 -0.0404555
wt    0.0336169  0.0067937 -0.0381530  0.0220001  0.0144280  0.0557339 -0.0456645  0.0068770 -0.0018885  0.0130414 -0.0517650
qsec -0.0305039  0.0235644  0.0234403  0.0058275  0.0114941 -0.0456645  0.1253074 -0.0550369  0.0505232  0.0153716  0.0311835
vs   -0.0053454  0.0365639  0.0099106 -0.0381702 -0.0063444  0.0068770 -0.0550369  0.2011561  0.0424050 -0.0077544  0.0144598
am   -0.0418918  0.0280907  0.0063967 -0.0138610 -0.0299061 -0.0018885  0.0505232  0.0424050  0.2007678 -0.0533956  0.0073674
gear -0.0148400  0.0382301 -0.0056446 -0.0143631 -0.0149503  0.0130414  0.0153716 -0.0077544 -0.0533956  0.1849591 -0.0651851
carb  0.0067390 -0.0205128  0.0494742 -0.0556935 -0.0404555 -0.0517650  0.0311835  0.0144598  0.0073674 -0.0651851  0.1260946

$Anti.Image.Cor
           mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear      carb
mpg   1.000000  0.023264 -0.160835  0.210520 -0.104455  0.393449 -0.238099 -0.032931 -0.258328 -0.095343  0.052437
cyl   0.023264  1.000000 -0.266365 -0.174760  0.271715  0.112864  0.261081  0.319738  0.245880  0.348639 -0.226561
disp -0.160835 -0.266365  1.000000 -0.540292 -0.096955 -0.761362  0.311958  0.104101  0.067255 -0.061832  0.656375
hp    0.210520 -0.174760 -0.540292  1.000000  0.062543  0.298903  0.052803 -0.272975 -0.099223 -0.107121 -0.503062
drat -0.104455  0.271715 -0.096955  0.062543  1.000000  0.112886  0.059977 -0.026129 -0.123284 -0.064210 -0.210438
wt    0.393449  0.112864 -0.761362  0.298903  0.112886  1.000000 -0.546425  0.064949 -0.017853  0.128448 -0.617488
qsec -0.238099  0.261081  0.311958  0.052803  0.059977 -0.546425  1.000000 -0.346656  0.318533  0.100970  0.248078
vs   -0.032931  0.319738  0.104101 -0.272975 -0.026129  0.064949 -0.346656  1.000000  0.211010 -0.040202  0.090792
am   -0.258328  0.245880  0.067255 -0.099223 -0.123284 -0.017853  0.318533  0.211010  1.000000 -0.277090  0.046304
gear -0.095343  0.348639 -0.061832 -0.107121 -0.064210  0.128448  0.100970 -0.040202 -0.277090  1.000000 -0.426837
carb  0.052437 -0.226561  0.656375 -0.503062 -0.210438 -0.617488  0.248078  0.090792  0.046304 -0.426837  1.000000

$KMO
[1] 0.82655

$MSA
         MSA
mpg  0.92757
cyl  0.89659
disp 0.76474
hp   0.83861
drat 0.94972
wt   0.74105
qsec 0.74009
vs   0.90669
am   0.87781
gear 0.84699
carb 0.62112

$Bartlett
[1] 408.01

$Communalities
     Initial Communalities Final Extraction
mpg                0.86902          0.85283
cyl                0.93499          0.93572
disp               0.95494          0.89800
hp                 0.90280          0.87629
drat               0.70690          0.70810
wt                 0.94427          0.82076
qsec               0.87469          0.78392
vs                 0.79884          0.70753
am                 0.79923          0.81597
gear               0.81504          0.80021
carb               0.87391          0.65842

$Iterations
[1] 6

$Eigenvalues
             0          1         2         3         4         5         6
 [1,] 6.608400  6.4855427  6.443771  6.437392  6.436563  6.436514  6.436540
 [2,] 2.650468  2.4860094  2.435203  2.424238  2.421814  2.421291  2.421192
 [3,] 0.627197  0.4906408  0.413020  0.394932  0.390219  0.388847  0.388409
 [4,] 0.269597  0.1239321  0.073905  0.065396  0.063847  0.063546  0.063490
 [5,] 0.223451  0.0903017  0.035016  0.028614  0.028742  0.029268  0.029567
 [6,] 0.211596  0.0027396 -0.016782 -0.013671 -0.011897 -0.011232 -0.011011
 [7,] 0.135262 -0.0086628 -0.023875 -0.026050 -0.025770 -0.025541 -0.025456
 [8,] 0.122901 -0.0332049 -0.058059 -0.058056 -0.056306 -0.055239 -0.054723
 [9,] 0.077047 -0.0462257 -0.075004 -0.078746 -0.079139 -0.079110 -0.079075
[10,] 0.052035 -0.0512176 -0.119330 -0.133641 -0.136766 -0.137461 -0.137609
[11,] 0.022044 -0.0652226 -0.136313 -0.161433 -0.169679 -0.172507 -0.173519

$Communality.Iterations
           0       1       2       3       4       5       6
mpg  0.86902 0.85130 0.85170 0.85250 0.85276 0.85282 0.85283
cyl  0.93499 0.92720 0.93177 0.93432 0.93529 0.93562 0.93572
disp 0.95494 0.90844 0.90029 0.89863 0.89819 0.89805 0.89800
hp   0.90280 0.87170 0.87174 0.87407 0.87542 0.87604 0.87629
drat 0.70690 0.70350 0.70659 0.70785 0.70813 0.70814 0.70810
wt   0.94427 0.85173 0.82916 0.82318 0.82146 0.82093 0.82076
qsec 0.87469 0.80788 0.79051 0.78573 0.78438 0.78401 0.78392
vs   0.79884 0.72128 0.70862 0.70714 0.70725 0.70743 0.70753
am   0.79923 0.79833 0.80625 0.81141 0.81408 0.81537 0.81597
gear 0.81504 0.79851 0.79846 0.79949 0.80001 0.80018 0.80021
carb 0.87391 0.73168 0.68388 0.66732 0.66140 0.65923 0.65842

$Criterion.Differences
               1          2          3          4          5          6
 [1,] 0.01771287 3.9858e-04 0.00079489 0.00026789 5.9642e-05 6.3003e-06
 [2,] 0.00779344 4.5755e-03 0.00254850 0.00096806 3.2722e-04 1.0556e-04
 [3,] 0.04650430 8.1489e-03 0.00166092 0.00043460 1.4408e-04 5.4580e-05
 [4,] 0.03109529 3.8492e-05 0.00232619 0.00135461 6.1323e-04 2.5343e-04
 [5,] 0.00340577 3.0901e-03 0.00125886 0.00028353 5.1726e-06 3.9186e-05
 [6,] 0.09253989 2.2567e-02 0.00598329 0.00172113 5.2875e-04 1.7058e-04
 [7,] 0.06680911 1.7372e-02 0.00477843 0.00134935 3.7368e-04 9.2860e-05
 [8,] 0.07756263 1.2664e-02 0.00148035 0.00010953 1.8154e-04 9.9521e-05
 [9,] 0.00089865 7.9189e-03 0.00515871 0.00266688 1.2883e-03 6.0753e-04
[10,] 0.01653524 4.2981e-05 0.00103130 0.00051693 1.6964e-04 2.7050e-05
[11,] 0.14222343 4.7805e-02 0.01655978 0.00591467 2.1707e-03 8.1552e-04

$Factor.Loadings
         [,1]      [,2]
mpg   0.92318 -0.023742
cyl  -0.96429 -0.076589
disp -0.94453  0.076585
hp   -0.84320 -0.406584
drat  0.73300 -0.413289
wt   -0.87742  0.225607
qsec  0.50415  0.727840
vs    0.76271  0.354693
am    0.59583 -0.678944
gear  0.52376 -0.725177
carb -0.52815 -0.616016

$Reproduced.Cor
          mpg      cyl     disp       hp      drat       wt      qsec       vs       am     gear     carb
mpg   1.00000 -0.88840 -0.87379 -0.76877  0.686505 -0.81537  0.448141  0.69570  0.56618  0.50074 -0.47295
cyl  -0.88840  1.00000  0.90493  0.84423 -0.675171  0.82880 -0.541891 -0.76264 -0.52255 -0.44952  0.55647
disp -0.87379  0.90493  1.00000  0.76528 -0.723989  0.84602 -0.420441 -0.69323 -0.61477 -0.55024  0.45167
hp   -0.76877  0.84423  0.76528  1.00000 -0.450025  0.64810 -0.721025 -0.78732 -0.22635 -0.14679  0.69579
drat  0.68651 -0.67517 -0.72399 -0.45003  1.000000 -0.73639  0.068733  0.41247  0.71734  0.68362 -0.13254
wt   -0.81537  0.82880  0.84602  0.64810 -0.736386  1.00000 -0.278142 -0.58919 -0.67596 -0.62316  0.32443
qsec  0.44814 -0.54189 -0.42044 -0.72102  0.068733 -0.27814  1.000000  0.64268 -0.19378 -0.26376 -0.71463
vs    0.69570 -0.76264 -0.69323 -0.78732  0.412472 -0.58919  0.642678  1.00000  0.21362  0.14226 -0.62132
am    0.56618 -0.52255 -0.61477 -0.22635  0.717341 -0.67596 -0.193777  0.21362  1.00000  0.80443  0.10356
gear  0.50074 -0.44952 -0.55024 -0.14679  0.683625 -0.62316 -0.263759  0.14226  0.80443  1.00000  0.17010
carb -0.47295  0.55647  0.45167  0.69579 -0.132540  0.32443 -0.714626 -0.62132  0.10356  0.17010  1.00000

$Residuals
            mpg         cyl       disp         hp       drat        wt      qsec        vs          am       gear      carb
mpg   0.0000000  3.6236e-02  0.0262378 -0.0073977 -0.0053331 -0.052288 -0.029457 -0.031657  3.3656e-02 -0.0204599 -0.077973
cyl   0.0362355  0.0000e+00 -0.0028993 -0.0117777 -0.0247674 -0.046308 -0.049351 -0.048177 -5.7169e-05 -0.0431696 -0.029480
disp  0.0262378 -2.8993e-03  0.0000000  0.0256657  0.0137755  0.041960 -0.013257 -0.017184  2.3544e-02 -0.0053252 -0.056696
hp   -0.0073977 -1.1778e-02  0.0256657  0.0000000  0.0012663  0.010644  0.012801  0.064226 -1.6854e-02  0.0210835  0.054018
drat -0.0053331 -2.4767e-02  0.0137755  0.0012663  0.0000000  0.023945  0.022472  0.027806 -4.6295e-03  0.0159856  0.041750
wt   -0.0522885 -4.6308e-02  0.0419598  0.0106436  0.0239453  0.000000  0.103426  0.034272 -1.6533e-02  0.0398744  0.103178
qsec -0.0294574 -4.9351e-02 -0.0132567  0.0128014  0.0224716  0.103426  0.000000  0.101858 -3.6084e-02  0.0510764  0.058377
vs   -0.0316568 -4.8177e-02 -0.0171839  0.0642264  0.0278062  0.034272  0.101858  0.000000 -4.5279e-02  0.0637630  0.051712
am    0.0336559 -5.7169e-05  0.0235439 -0.0168536 -0.0046295 -0.016533 -0.036084 -0.045279  0.0000e+00 -0.0103665 -0.046021
gear -0.0204599 -4.3170e-02 -0.0053252  0.0210835  0.0159856  0.039874  0.051076  0.063763 -1.0366e-02  0.0000000  0.103976
carb -0.0779730 -2.9480e-02 -0.0566963  0.0540175  0.0417504  0.103178  0.058377  0.051712 -4.6021e-02  0.1039762  0.000000

$RMS
[1] 0.044193

$call
paf(object = "as.matrix(mtcars)", eigcrit = 1, convcrit = 0.001)

$items
 [1] ""                       "Correlation"            "Anti.Image.Cov"         "Anti.Image.Cor"         "KMO"                   
 [6] "MSA"                    "Bartlett"               "Communalities"          "Iterations"             "Eigenvalues"           
[11] "Communality.Iterations" "Criterion.Differences"  "Factor.Loadings"        "Reproduced.Cor"         "Residuals"             
[16] "RMS"                    "call"                  

attr(,"class")
[1] "paf"  "list"
>
```